# How do you log a login failure in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony4

### My Question

What sort of Response should I return that won't change the default response?  Or is there a better way to tack on a logger to a Login Failure/badcredentialsexception?

### Details

I found this post [here](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-customize-the-security-features-with-ease#customizing-authentication-failures-and-successes) which states that you can (in Symfony 2.4) customize authentication failures or successes like so:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class CustomTimeAuthenticator extends TimeAuthenticator implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface, AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        error_log('You are out!');
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        error_log(sprintf('Yep, you are in "%s"!', $token->getUsername()));
    }
}
```

It also states that

> ...you can also bypass the default behavior altogether by returning a
>   Response instance:

```
public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($exception->getCode()) {
        return new Response('Not the right time to log in, come back later.');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it seems in Symfony 4 [you have to return a Response](https://api.symfony.com/4.1/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface.html) (unlike the above 2.4 code) and so my code is:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class LoginFailureLogger implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    private $logger;
    private $security;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $security, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        $user = $exception->getToken()->getUser();

        $this->logger->notice('Failed to login user: "'. $user. '"".  Reason: '. $exception->getMessage());
    }
}
```

But when the page runs I get:

> Authentication Failure Handler did not return a Response.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot any longer return a response? Not only you can but also you have to.

Comment: I mean apparently (give that code for Symfony 2.4) you used to be able to just log something and that was it, now you have to return a Response.  Edited the post to make that more clear

Comment: What do you want to happen after the log? what should the user see?

Comment: Whatever the default is if I didn't implement that handler?  I mean right now without the handler it just throws them back to the login page and I check for login errors with $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError(); to add to a flash message

Comment: Basically I just want to tack on something to the loginfailure, not overwrite it.  It seems like 2.4 you had the ability to tack on OR overwrite it, now it's just always overwrite.  Basically this is a the difference between for instance LogoutHandlerInterface and LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just redirect to login page since this is the default behaviour. Please modify upon your specific requirements if any.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface;
...

private $flashBag;
private $logger;
private $security;

public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $security, LoggerInterface $logger, FlashBagInterface $flashBag)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->security = $security;
    $this->flashBag = $flashBag;
}

public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    $user = $exception->getToken()->getUser();

    $this->logger->notice('Failed to login user: "'. $user. '"".  Reason: '. $exception->getMessage());

    $this->flashBag()->add('notice', 'Failed to login.');

    return new RedirectResponse('/login');
}
```

**EDIT**: Added flash message

Comment: Actually I found a problem with this.  If I redirect with RedirectResponse, it apparently doesn't pass the exception on to the flash. How can I either forward the exception on or just invoke the flashbag in that service?

Comment: Yeah I actually thought that was what I was supposed to do too (and had tried that before you responded) but I get Cannot autowire service "app.login.failure": argument "$session" of method "App\Security\LoginFailureLogger::__construct()" references class "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session" but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface" instead.

Comment: Actually, was able to do this with FlashBagInterface $flashBag instead of Session $session, dunno if you want to update your answer *shrugs*.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Edited to use FlashBagInterface